# SwiftUI - .append in init function doesn't work

Tags: swift, initialization, swiftui

I have a `struct` called `Tile` that is declared like so:

```
struct Tile {
    var index: Int
    var value: String
}
```

I also have a few `State` variables:

```
@State var rows: Int
@State var cols: Int
@State var tiles: [Tile]
@State var texts: [String]
```

I have this `init` function:

```
init() {
    _rows = State(initialValue: 3)
    _cols = State(initialValue: 3)
    _tiles = State(initialValue: [])
    _texts = State(initialValue: [])
    for i in 0...self.rows*self.cols-1 {
        let tile = Tile(index: i+1, value: String(format: "%02d", i+1))
        tiles.append(tile)
        texts.append(tile.value)
    }
}
```

However, setting a breakpoint shows that the arrays are not actually appending the values to the arrays. Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`@State` variables can only be modified outside of init function. If you try to modify them directly in init there will be no effect - unless you're initialising them (like `State(initialValue: rows)`).

Try the following instead:

```
init() {
    let rows = 3
    let cols = 3
    var tiles = [Tile]()
    var texts = [String]()
    for i in 0...(rows * cols - 1) {
        let tile = Tile(index: i+1, value: String(format: "%02d", i+1))
        tiles.append(tile)
        texts.append(tile.value)
    }
    _rows = State(initialValue: rows)
    _cols = State(initialValue: cols)
    _tiles = State(initialValue: tiles)
    _texts = State(initialValue: texts)
}
```

Comment: Only `var` instead of `let`